# Gravatar gone in Safari 4

Tags: bug, status-declined, gravatar

I am using a gravatar linked to my account in openID, and for the last two months I've noticed a bug with Safari's (4.0.5) cache when handling the avatar image.

This:

[image: http://i51.tinypic.com/1zvc07s.png]

I know this is related to Safari's cache, because as soon as I empty it it shows the avatar again, but can this have some bug on SO side?

Comment: We literally render a `<img>` element pointing at gravatar there...it could be some crazy bug of ours I'm unaware of with the structure of the page, but it'd definitely be a new one on me.

Comment: Why just don't switch to Safari 5?

Comment: @shabunc: It still happens with Safari 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this before, and it's definitely just an issue with Safari caching the response served up by Gravatar. For some reason, and only on *rare* occasions, Gravatar seems to serve up something that Safari doesn't like and it caches that response. Why? I don't know. I guess that Gravatar have a minor intermittent issue which means they serve up the wrong message (maybe related to their system load?) and Safari has a minor bug in its cache management. Two minor things *in combination* become an occasional frustration for a few people.

What this definitely isn't is a bug with StackOverflow (or any other SE site) as they just serve up the correct link inside an `<img>` tag. Nor is it anything that they can do anything about.

Comment: I emphasize that I do not _know_ that this is what's going on. I do know that clearing the cache is the only fix. You've found that already.